# Arithmetic/Geometric series

Tags: ruby

The code below returns "Arithmetic", "Geometric" if the input array is an arithmetic and geometric series respectively and -1 if it is neither.

Although the code works fine, when I change

```
if s = arr.length - 1
```

to

```
if s == arr.length - 1
```

in the `while` loop, the code is not working properly anymore.

I do not understand why. Shouldn't `==` work instead of `=`?

```
def ArithGeo(arr)

  # code goes here
  len = arr.length
  difference = arr[len-1] - arr[len-2]
  ratio = arr[len-1]/arr[len-2]

  k = 0 
  s = k + 1


  while (arr[s] - arr[k]) == difference && s < arr.length
    if s = arr.length - 1
      return "Arithmetic"
    end
    k += 1
  end

  k = 0 

  while arr[s] / arr[k] == ratio && s < arr.length
    if s = arr.length - 1
      return "Geometric"
    end
    k += 1
  end

  return -1 

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never changing the value of `s` which I think you want to do. You should do that at the point that you increment `k`

```
k += 1
s = k + 1
```

Also, at the point where you reinitialize `k` for the geometric test, you want to reset `s` as well...

```
k = 0
s = k + 1
```

You could also get rid of the variable `s` completely and make it a method... add these three lines at the top of the code

```
def s(k)
  k + 1
end
```

And remove all the lines where you assign a value to `s` and use `s(k)`... `s(k)` will be a method that always returns the next higher value to `k`

Answer (score 2):

The difference between those two statements is that variable `s` is set for the first statement but not for the second. The first `if` statement has thus a side effect of setting `s` to `arr.length - 1`

```
if s =  arr.length - 1  # s => arr.length - 1
if s == arr.length - 1  # s => undefined
```

Because the `if` statement is inside a `while` loop which uses `s` in its expression the change of the statement changes the behavior of the programm.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `==` the statement will try to check if they are equals , with just `=` the statement work properly because your are only setting  the value to a value , so this is always true.

If it's different compare something to equals than just set a variable , that can be always true.